# Show both, major (year) and minor (month) tick

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following minimal examples shows not all minor labels.
Which minor labels are shown seem to depend on the major lables.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

dates = pd.date_range(start="2020-01-01", end="2023-01-01", freq="MS")

data = pd.Series(np.random.randint(5, 30, size=len(dates)), index=dates)

plt.plot(data.index, data.values)

ax = plt.gca()

ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%b"))
ax.set_xticks(
    ax.get_xticks(minor=True),
    ax.get_xticklabels(minor=True),
    rotation=90,
    fontsize=8,
    minor=True,
)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator(month=6))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("\n%Y"))

plt.show()
```

Here is the figure:

[image]

How do I show all minor labels (month)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you are looking for, there are a couple of things you need to do.

1. Set the `ax.remove_overlapping_locs` to false. This is the key as it will NOT remove minor ticks where major ticks are present. Some more information [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/matplotlib-axis-axis-remove_overlapping_locs-function-in-python/)
2. Set the tick lines to be the same size for major and minor x-ticks, so that the months appear neatly in the same line.
3. Rotate the minor ticks. Updated code below.

Note that I have used figsize so that the figure is longer, although not necessary. Feel free to remove that.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

dates = pd.date_range(start="2020-01-01", end="2023-01-01", freq="MS")

data = pd.Series(np.random.randint(5, 30, size=len(dates)), index=dates)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,5))
plt.plot(data.index, data.values)
#ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.remove_overlapping_locs = False

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("\n\n%Y"))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%b"))

ax.tick_params('x', length=4, width=1, which='both')
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which="minor", rotation=90, labelsize=8)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Months are not necessarily minor ticks, they can also be major ticks. When you do

```py
ax.set_xticks(
    ax.get_xticks(minor=True),
    ax.get_xticklabels(minor=True),
    rotation=90,
    fontsize=8,
    minor=True,
)
```

You are replacing all ticks with just the minor ticks. If you just want to apply a transformation to the months, I would recommend replacing the above code chunk with a simple

```py
ax.tick_params(axis="x", which="minor", rotation=90, labelsize=8)
```

If you want to keep your methodology, simply change the order of your code as follows.

```
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%b"))

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator(month=6))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("\n%Y")) 

ax.set_xticks(
    ax.get_xticks(minor=True),
    ax.get_xticklabels(minor=True),
    rotation=90,
    fontsize=8,
    minor=True,
)
```

Comment: This still doesn't show the month ticks for which a major tick is shown. In the example above this would be `Jun`. How to display all month labels?

Comment: Your line `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator(month=6))` locates the year label at the 6th month, June. Do you want all months + year? I'm not sure that is possible using the current method...

Comment: That is exactly what I want to achieve.